# Converting mp4 AAC to AVC using Python

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

i am using `ffmpeg` to convert video format. I have a video in `mp4 aac` and want to convert it to `mp4 avc`. I successfully(!!!) used `ffmpeg` to covert image to `avi`/`mkv`/even copy of the `mp4` but nothing gives me what i desire. 
 The idea is to have a video file format that will run on mostly all mobile devices such as `mp4 avc`.

My python code:

```
import subprocess #need to install ffmpegin terminal/cmd

def convert_video(video_input, video_output):
    cmds = ['ffmpeg', '-i', video_input, video_output]
    subprocess.Popen(cmds)


convert_video("videoName.mp4", "videoNameCopy.mp4")
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Does it throw an error?

Comment: aac is an audio format, avc is a video format. Why are you trying to convert audio to video?

Comment: I downloaded a video from youtube for a check and it says the file is mp4 aac and it wont play on android also i can play it in browser and iphone

Comment: So the actual issue is that you have an output from ffmpeg that does not play on Android? Show your ffmpeg command and the complete log. This seems like an issue of ffmpeg usage, and does not seem to have anything to do with python. So skip the python stuff for now until you resolve whatever issue you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to convert your VIDEO codec from hevc to h.264 (a.k.a avc bp):

```
import subprocess
    def convert_video(video_input, video_output):
    subprocess.run(rf" -i video_input -c:v libx264 -c:a aac video_output")

convert_video("users/vids/.../input.mp4", "users/vids/.../output.mp4")
```

This converts the video and keeps the audio.

Comment: I tried what you suggest but the image is still AAC after conversion. Here is an image to show the file codec after convertion - https://ibb.co/tqH5tWk

Comment: @zion.b. avc is not an audio codec, avc is a name for a video type. What is your end goal?

Comment: @zion.b. The most common file type, which is practically universal is h.264 aac.